# UI object catches click event even by clicking outside of that object

Tags: unity

I'm running to a weird issue where I have a Canvas and some objects on it which are adding as prefabs. Each object has a OnClick event attached to it. The problem comes in when I click somewhere in Canvas only to see one of those prefabs catch the click event (and I don't know which one got it).

The whole thing was working good, till it wasn't anymore. I'm not sure if I did something or maybe it happens after updating Unity.

Here's some more details:

- I guess the problem happened after installing Unity Pro 2017.1
- I've changed the ordering layers in some different ways and problem still was around!
- I'm using `IPointerClickHandler` for receiving click events.
- I've removed UI elements one by one in play mode to check if it makes any differences. The problem stays until I remove the last object which has the script for receiving click event.
- Maybe it worth mention that the prefabs are adding to a parent with grid layout group.

Has anyone ran to this issue before or has any idea why this would happen?

**UPDATE**

Screenshot included:

[image]

Comment: How do you know that the event is in fact being intercepted by one of the objects? Is this happening even when clicking outside all other clickable areas -- like when clicking anywhere on the canvas at all? A screenshot would help.

Comment: @TartleWizard Screenshot included